# Laravel Notification Markdown - Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, markdown

I am getting the following error when trying to pass data to a markdown mailable

`Undefined variable: claim`

I have the following code for a notification

```
class ChequeDiscrepancy extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }


    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Subject')
            ->markdown('emails.admin.banking.cheque_discrepancy');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

In my markdown template, I have

```
@component('mail::message')
# Cheque No: {{$data->id}}
@endcomponent
```

According to https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#view-data I should be able to pass the data via public properties or via The with Method. This works for regular mail but doesn't seem to work for notifications.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you use a variable `$claim`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data is different between Notifications & Mailable classes.
In notifications you need to pass the data explicitly, like this

```php
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Subject')
            ->markdown('emails.admin.banking.cheque_discrepancy', ['data'=>$this->data]);
    }
```

You may read further here : [Laravel Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#other-mail-notification-formatting-options)